# Where should I put static files in my extension that are just used in certain few pages?

Tags: gsoc

I need to use few static files(images, css) in one of my template. Currently I am using a CDN link to the same, but in practice storing the same within the extension will ensure the availability even if the links stop working.

Where should I put such files in my extension, should putting them in the template folder itself is the right practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically your extension directory would contain subdirectories named `css` and `js` and resources of those types would go in there.

To load them on-demand, use [CRM_Core_Resources](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resource+Reference).